# Diodes Circuit Analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes

[image]

3.29(b)
I solved this and got Vout = Vin - (Vb - Vd) when diode with Vb is conducting and got Vout = (Vin - 0.8)R2 / (R1 + R2) when upper diode was conducting but unable to find the output voltage when both of them are conducting.

Can someone please help me out?[image]

Comment: Post a nice clear, cropped photo of the plot showing the curve for the regions you have worked out.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am uploading it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll offer a visual approach to the solution.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fj7LMg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Three cases. The arrows are the direction of the current.*

- (Not shown in Figure 1.) When Vi = Vb - Vd (1.3 V using a typical diode) there is current around the D1 D2 loop but no current in the outer loop. This is where you curve crosses the X-axis.
- a. The easiest case: When Vi is high D4 is reverse biased and so that branch is out of circuit. That gives right-side portion of your graph.
- b. When Vi < Vb - Vd some current will flow in the D1 D2 loop but current will also flow in the outer loop. This gives the left-side portion of your graph.
- c. In the in-between cases Vo will rise from 0 to the upper line.

Sorry, this needs more work. Saving incomplete solution for later editing.